# rowMean based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, excel, conditional-statements, mean

I want to calculate a rowMean across two columns if the conditions below are met. If not return NA.

This is how I would write it in Excel. Can anyone suggest how I might do this in R?

```
=IF(OR(AND(V1>=3,V2>=0),AND(V1>=2,V2>=1),AND(V1>=1,V2>=2)),(V3+V4)/(V5+V6),NA)
```

I've written basic If statements in R, but can't visualise this other than writing it as above.

Comment: Have you tried calling `ifelse()`?

Comment: An ugly way to go around this is to create some binary flags, which can then be summarised.  Do you have a sample data set?

Comment: `ifelse( (V1 >= 3 & V2 >= 0 ) | ( V1>=2 & V2>=1 ) | ( V1>=1 & V2>=2) , (V3+V4)/(V5+V6) , NA )`

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Make it an answer.

Comment: @Thomas nah. I can't even test it to make sure it does what I expect without doing extra work so I won't post it. Feel free if you have confidence in me!! :-) (plus from above it's not obvious to me how the resultant calculation is actually a `rowMean`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a is your data.frame and you want to use a loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(a)){
a$results[i] <- ifelse( (a[i,1]>=3 & a[i,2]>=0) | (a[i,1] >=2 & a[i,2] >= 1) | ..., mean(a[i,1],a[i,2]), NA) # & is the AND | is the OR 
}
```

The better way would be to define a function for the job and use apply to loop through the data.frame.

```
f <- function(x){
ifelse((x[1]>=3 & x[2]>=0) | (x[1] >=2 & x[2] >= 1) | ..., mean(x[1],x[2]), NA)
}

a$results <- apply(a,1,f)
```